# Microsoft graph list memebers of a group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying now to list all members of an AAD group with GraphApi. The problem is that the responses are received in pages with 70 users, even if in documentation is specified that will be 100 users per page. The question is how to get all users of a group? I tried this:

```
var users = await _graphClient.Groups[id].Members.Request().GetAsync();

        while (users.Count > 0)
        {
            members.AddRange(users.OfType<Microsoft.Graph.User>());
            if (users.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                users = await users.NextPageRequest
                    .GetAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

But I think that it could have quite awful performance since every time it gets evaluated, we have to enumerate the entire result set before returning anything. I can't imagine how will this perform when there are 5000 users? It will need about 70 requests, and the response time will be very long. Does someone know how to return all users in one request or to skip a count of users? Skip method is now supported by the service when returning the list of users

Comment: You can try to get upto 999 users per page using 'Top' operator. Later you should use the nextlink from that page and get the next set of 999 users. This can help you get the 5000 records in just 6 requests. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter

Answer (score 0):

That's by design there is no way to fetch >100 at once on this endpoint.

Depending on your scenario there are some options:

- **List is used in a UX component**: then I would implement the same paging/filter restriction that this endpoint is given.
- **List is used to process all members**: then I would create an async architecture to process the command. Like a queue and a function. (Check out durable function that can fan out.) Providing a status of the command. So users can monitor the progress of the command. While doing something else.